# Matrix algebra over division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have read that matrix ring over a commutative ring forms an associative algebra so we call the matrix ring as matrix algebra. But I have seen that when we are considering a matrix ring over a division ring (which is not necessarily commutative) are also named as matrix algebra. Is this ring also forms an algebra or any other logic behind it?

Comment: Could you be more precise, please? Where did you find matrix rings over noncommutative rings being called *algebras*? Because there are some generalizations of the term *algebra* to noncommutative setting (see e.g. [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/21899/definition-of-an-algebra-over-a-noncommutative-ring)), but it may depend on what your reference define "algebra"

Comment: An Introduction to Group Rings by Polcino Milies, César, Sehgal, Sudarshan states that (Wedderburn-Artin Theorem, pg 104, Theorem 2.6.18) A ring $R$ is semisimple if and only if it is a direct sum of matrix algebras over division rings. I want to know why are they calling a matrix ring over a division ring, a matrix algebra ?